# Why has this question been put on hold as 'off topic?'

Tags: support

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/387381/single-word-or-phrase-synonymous-with-single-word-request

My recent question for a single word or phrase that can replace 'single word' as in "what is a 'single word' for 'this description of something'" has now been placed on hold as off topic even after I edited the question to make the context clear, giving examples, and after substantial discussion had occurred in comments. **I should like to know why it was put on hold so that I can try to improve the question and bring it on-topic.**

EDIT: I have only now received the earlier very clear explanatory comment

> "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not attempt to solve an actual problem that someone is having" -- tchrist

I assure you it is an actual problem that I am having and not hypothetical. I perceive the use of 'single-word-request' as awkward and wanted to know whether there is any other word or phrase to cover the meaning. For example, since we have the word 'synonym', it would be awkward to read a sentence such as "can you suggest a **same-meaning-word** for 'elementary?'" -- if no such word/phrase for 'single word' exists, can somebody say so and I'll accept the answer!

Comment: *Managgia*, if this question hadn't been close we could have directed Cerberus to it when he posted [his SWR](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/442974/word-for-a-single-word-request) in April.

Comment: Too right @Mari-lou A -- A bizarre duplicate of a bizarre SWR!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your post has been edited several times but does not offer a consistent question.

Your title asks for a synonym for 'single-word-request'. Your original question in the last paragraph asks for a single word that could replace 'single-word-request'.

Your first and second edits ask for a word or phrase for 'a single word or phrase' that fits in "What's a _____ for {some word}?" that means "a single word or phrase". Sentence with a blank is good, that gives us some context to work with. It would also be helpful to describe what you've thought of using and why you feel it doesn't fit in your sentence.

Your post-script suggests coining a term based on mononym. (We don't generally do that here.)

So, pick which thing you are asking about, 'single word or phrase' or 'single word request'. If you are asking for a single word or phrase, then you need to explain why "single word or phrase" doesn't work, because that is a phrase that describes exactly what you are asking for. If you are asking for a word for single word request, then you need to provide an example of the context so we can help.

Also, the word you want is *term*.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and detailed answer. I shall try to edit for consistency and present a few examples.

Comment: [term](https://www.google.com/search?q=definition+term) can be more than one word, so I think it does not fit  the criterion of being synonymous with 'single word'.

Comment: +1 for "Also, the word you want is *term*." :)

Comment: You mean if it had been written like Cerberus's  question [Word for a Single-Word Request](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/442974/word-for-a-single-word-request) which was posted  Apr 22 of this year, and  currently stands at +2.